# Finding a Fourier Serie from uniform converge

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Question: Let $f(x)=x-x^2$ in $[0,1]$. Define the Fourier Serie in that interval.

My Try: I define the Fourier Serie to $g(x)=x$ in $[0,1]$ as $\mathcal{F(g)}$. As $f$ is continuous, differentiable by parts and $f(0)=f(1)$, so I intend to use the theorem of uniform converge for Fourier Serie of $f$ so that

$$\int_{0}^{x} f'(t) dt =\int_{0}^{x}  g'(t)dt - \int_{0}^{x} 2g(t)dt$$

My question is: Can I do the integration using the the fundamental theorem of calculus for $f'(t)$ and $g'(t)$ (and replace by $\mathcal{F(g)}$ of $g$, again because the uniform convergence of this) and for $2g(t)$ integration term-by-term of the $2\mathcal{F(g)}$?

Although, I know that can do the problem in a straightforward way using definitions, I want to learn the theorems to make easier the calculations.

Comment: You better not to do this. Because the problem won't get any easier

Comment: I don't understand why the question was downvote. Can someone explain me? I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: It wasn't me for sure! But maybe because your question was vague. I didn't fully understand what you want to do. What's your motivation for this way of dealing with the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the Fourier series for $g(x)=x$ on $[0,1]$:
$$
x=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a_ne^{2\pi i nx}\tag{1}
$$

To get the Fourier series of $x^2$ from (1), you need to do integration term by term, which would be justified by uniform convergence of the Fourier series.

---

If you don't know how to deal with the exponential functions, then just rewrite (1) by using the Euler formula $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$.

Comment: Jack, I'm not using the complex form yet. I can apply your suggestion using the real form?

Comment: I would not call it "real form" though, but they are essentially the same.